# What is the facebook.com/sharer.php ios/android url schema for mobile websites?

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is the facebook.com/sharer.php available through android/ios url schemas? I have a website with a lot of fb traffic, however most people come from the fb app. If they press the share button on my mobile website I want the facebook app to open and display the sharing dialog. The problem with using facebook mobile is that a lof of users are signed in into the facebook app, but not in the mobile browser!

thx, I appreciate your help!

best

Comment: I guess you should use Feed dialog instead of Sharer.php. As sharer.php is deprecated.

Please read this doc 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0

Comment: ok, but feed dialog doesn't open the app either or? ... ok just check. for me on nexus5 facebook isn't opened! Is the feed dialog opening the app on ios?