# sharing a specific page using fb:// url scheme on iOS

Tags: php, ios, facebook, mobile

I am using  Ridiculously Responsive Social Sharing Buttons http://www.kurtnoble.com/labs/rrssb to allow users to share a specific page of web content to facebook.

I usually write a "mobile version" of the buttons to they will link to the app on a smartphone. So:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/...foo">
```

on mobile, becomes:

```
<a href="fb://...foo">
```

What I cannot to is pass the actual web page to the app. The link looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" class="popupWin">
```

What I want to do is hide the "https" link on mobile, and show the "fb:" link (which is easy with .js or css)

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Sorry - I can't figure out how to write the smartphone "FB://" version of the dynamicly generated, page specific "https://" link

or,

how can I write a link tag to share a specific page of web content to the face book app?

Comment: Try replacing `https://www.facebook.com/` with `fb://`, leaving the url as `fb://sharer/sharer.php?u=http://?<php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>`. I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: I did try that first off, and it does load the app, just loads the standard news feed (doesn't post a link, etc)

Comment: Maybe the `fb://` doesn't allow you to access to the sharer file.

Comment: it doesn't appear to. I'm not sure this is possible at all really...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/ this page seems to be very close, it however, still links to the website, not the app.

Comment: That one uses the file `https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php` instead. Try `fb://sharer.php` and pray for it to work. I saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157059/what-is-the-facebook-com-sharer-php-ios-android-url-schema-for-mobile-websites  which is inconclusive but makes me think that you can't make the app work (which makes no sense).

Comment: In the case that they use `fb://` only to access a profile name, then you have to stick with the link you provided.